# Rollback does not work using MongoTransactionManager

Tags: spring, mongodb, transactions

Hello I am developping a back-end using Spring boot and MongoDB 4.0. In order to add transactions I have implemented the MongoTransactionManager as seen in the documentations [spring mongo transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.RC2/reference/html/#mongo.transactions)

```
@Bean
MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDbFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}
```

But when I annotate a method with @Transactional(rollbackFor = NullPointerException.class) it does not roll back for this exception. 
For example the following test does not work.
Do you have any advices to fix this issue please ?

```
@Test
@Transactional(rollbackFor = NullPointerException.class)
public void testTransaction() {
    try {
        myRepo.deleteAll();
        throw new NullPointerException();
       } catch (
        NullPointerException e) {
    } finally {
        assertThat(myRepo.findAll()).isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figure it out that MongoTransactionManager does not work if you also register a Bean MongoTemplate. 
Moreover, surprinsingly, @Transactional method does not work if it is a @Test method. You must extract the @Transactional method in a @Service.

Answer (score 0):

Because you just caught your NPE and didn't do anything with it. For transaction being rollbacked your method should throw NPE out of the method.